# How do you center divs using only CSS

Tags: css

I currently use this way to center divs using a table and CSS:

```
<table width="69" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="59">
      <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="position:absolute; text-align:left; top: 100px;">div2 content goes here</div>
        <div style="position:absolute;text-align:left;">div content goes here</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the sample: http://2slick.com/div_center.html

Notice how expanding the browser doesn't change the centering of the divs.  Does anyone know a way to do something similar using CSS and less code?

Answer (score 2):

Give the div a fixed width and set both left and right margins to auto.

```
.centeredDiv {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Common method is without using a table, set div `margin:0 auto` in its style.

Answer (score 0):

Using a table isn't the best idea when trying to do positioning, unless you're displaying data.  If you're trying to use a center layout page design check this out: http://simplebits.com/notebook/2004/09/08/centering/

Answer (score 0):

```
margin:auto
```

Should do the trick on the centered div. To recreate your example pretty closely:

```
<div style="width:100px; margin:auto">
    <div style="width:100px;">div content goes here</div>
    <div style="width:100px;">div2 content goes here</div>
</div>
```

You can then add padding, text alignment etc as needed. Also good to get the inline styles out, but for examples inline is convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Just set auto margins. See this page:
http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

Answer (score 0):

Here goes...

CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    }
div {
    width: 59px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div>I'm a div!</div>
<div>So am I!</div>
```